# How to use `@` as a function in laravel 6

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

I am building a website and I'm creating an admin and user login form but I'm facing some problems because when I try to type for example `@extends` or any other function with `@` it doest change color or do anything (sorry for not being to clear). So basically it doesn't act as a function but just as a simple text that later shows up at the display on the website. If anyone can help me i would be very happy because I have been trying for hours and its important for me to finish this website

[Image of code in my editor where the color is not changing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3JIKM.png)

[Image of code that isn't working correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RmfZn.png)

[adminLoginController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQMZo.png)

[This is what i get on localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvfnx.png)

[This is what i did trying to add layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hRsO.png)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202532/discussion-on-question-by-natalie-how-to-use-as-a-function-in-laravel-6).

Comment: You need to ensure that the blade file is in the correct location eg.

Answer (score 1):

The lack of color highlighting is "syntax highlighting". Your editor would need support for Blade to be able to highlight the Blade syntax correctly.

The Blade **directive** `@extends` needs to take an argument/expression:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
```

> "When defining a child view, use the Blade `@extends` directive to specify which layout the child view should "inherit".

[Laravel 6.x Docs - Blade - Extending a Layout](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/blade#extending-a-layout) `@extends()`

When it comes to rendering these templates, just make sure the file ends with `.blade.php` if you want it to be a Blade template.

> "Blade view files use the `.blade.php` file extension and are typically stored in the `resources/views` directory."

[Laravel 6.x Docs - Blade - Introduction](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/blade#introduction)

**Update:**

You do not have a `layouts` directory in `resources/views`. You need to extend an existing layout. By the looks of your structure you mean to extend `auth.layouts.app`:

```
@extends('auth.layouts.app')
```

Also you are not defining a `@section('content')` to be `@yield`ed in the layout.

```
@extends('what.ever.layout.you.want.to.use')

@section('content)
    <!-- your content here -->
@endsection
```

Comment: +1 because people who downvote with no explanation are not helpful. Also your answer is correct - @Natalie , your second screenshot is not using the @extends directive properly. Please use it as a function `extends('another.component')` as posted in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure your blade file filenames are in the format of:

```
my_custom_file.blade.php
```

And not just:

```
my_custom_file.php
```

If you just end your files in `.php` then Laravel will not process it as a Blade template. The `@extends` directive is a Blade template feature and will need to be pre-processed into regular PHP by Laravel for it to work. It does this automatically when you use the `return view('my_custom_view')` syntax. This line would look for a file in `resources/views/my_custom_view.blade.php` first.

Comment: yea not sure why the hit and run on the answers, but your answer was my first assumption as well

Answer (score 0):

From your file structure layouts.blade.php is located in your views directory, so what you need to do is:

@extends('layouts')

To extend the layouts.blade.php